# How to change a total supply of tokens on an existing ether contract?

Tags: gas

I created my token using token factory but I sent them by accident to MEW address and not meta mask address - I didn't send eth to my contract address via meta mask so all my tokens got lost. I really like my token name and I would like to increase total supply but I don't know how. Could you please provide me with a short step by step instructions how to do that? You'd save my day :) Thank you, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "MEW address" or a "MetaMask address." If you have the private key that goes with an address, you can use that address with any tool. I'm unclear on what happened or what sending ether has to do with anything, but if your issue is just "I don't know how to transfer tokens from account A to account B using tool X?" please explain more about the accounts and the tools you're using. I haven't seen the code for your token, but typically it's not possible to increase the total supply.

Comment: Did you send real Ether to your token contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First

You can deploy new contract with the same name, but with a new initial supply, there is no problem in that.

### Second

According to [this](https://github.com/ConsenSys/Token-Factory/blob/master/contracts/HumanStandardToken.sol) code your initial supply is defined on contract initiation and there is no functionality to change it once it is deployed.

### Third

Just `transfer` tokens from your MEW address to MetaMask address(in case you cannot log in to the same account using MM).

Comment: Thanks. I think that there was a gas problem. I sent my tokens from the contract address to MEW address (from which I didn't create a contract initially but with metamask account). So there was no gas involved and I lost all my tokens but are you saying that I can create a new contract with my metamask account under the same name and same token symbol and everything will be ok?

Comment: It will be brand new contract address, but with the same name and token symbol and new initial supply. Just use your metamask when you will deploy it and by default you will have all of the supplied tokens.

Comment: Thanks. I created a new contract and token factory says Transverring amount. Awaiting confirmation. After 15 minutes I still don't see the balance on my metamask account... How long do I have to wait? How can I check if everything is correct? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using the correct network with your metamask? Have you added the token to your metamask account? You need to have contract address in order to `add` token and then to see it in your `tokens` tab.

Comment: Yes I did all of that but seams to me everything went wrong like the first time... my balance says: 0.00000001 tokens! It should be 10000000000 I entered in token factory 10000000000 and 18 decimal places and seams to me I have only 0.00000001 tokens, I'm puzzled, how can that be?

Comment: It should be ‘amount * 10e18’.

Comment: I just realized that decimal places are not what I thought they are... I have to  put a number with 18 zeros besides the number of tokens I want. I'll try that. It should work. Thanks.

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept the [Answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you have other specific questions please use [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).